# Serial connection cannot send login information

Tags: login, serial-console

I'm connected through a serial port to my Raspberry Pi 4 as:
PC <--> USB adapter <--> serial port <--> RPI

I enabled the shell login through the serial port with raspi-config and I can connect and see data from the serial port with:
`sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`
As the RPI boots, I can see in the `screen` terminal the login shell asking for an username, yet, I cannot pass from there. I write the username and enter, but no password is asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused due to a faulty TX wire. I checked with a different USB adapter and all good

Comment: Please accept your own answer so it doesn't appear on the homepage!