# Test functionality of a PL2303 USB-to-UART converter

Tags: serial, uart

I want to connect my computer to my raspberry pi (Model 3 A+) via serial console. Here is what I did (following the setup instructions described [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=148208)):

1. In the Raspbian OS enable serial in the advanced options, reboot
2. Edit `/boot/config.txt` and add

   ```
   core_freq=250
   enable_uart=1
   ```
3. Edit `/boot/cmdline.txt`, change `console=tty1` to `console=serial0`, shutdown the pi
4. Connect a Prolific PL2303 adapter to the pi and my computer (Black cable is GND and goes to Pin #6, White cable is RXD and goes to Pin #8, Green cable is TXD and goes to Pin #10)
5. Running `dmesg` on my computer shows me that the adapter is the device `/dev/ttyUSB0`
6. Run `sudo screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200` on the computer -> shows me an empty terminal
7. Start the pi. After a while, the terminal shows the pi's login screen, as expected

The problem is that my terminal shows the login screen, but I cannot type anything in. Running `dmesg` shows the following error:

```
pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303_get_line_request - failed: -32
```

Googling around a bit the best possible reason I could find is that [my adapter's TXD signal might be faulty](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/144179/serial-connection-cannot-send-login-information). But I would like to validate this before I try to get a refund. Is there a trivial way to test whether the adapter is broken? I thought something along the lines of connecting the adapter's TXD and RXD and checking if sending on one receives on the other, if that makes sense. I also have a multimeter at hand if that helps.

Or might my adapter be alright and the error is elsewhere?

Comment: If you want help you need to explain WHAT YOU DID (in your question) not post a link to a discussion forum.

Comment: @Milliways wdym? The post on the forum is a step-by-step instruction on how to set up the pi and what to run on the computer. This is exactly what I did

Comment: links die ... the question becomes useless without them ... the question and answers are not here for your personal benefit, but as a source of information for future research

Comment: `I thought something along the lines of connecting the adapter's TXD and RXD` ... why didn't you do that?

Comment: Alright I edited the question, hope it is clearer now

Comment: @jsotola `... why didn't you do that?` First I don't know if it is even a valid idea, second I don't know how to run some kind of diagnostic to check the functionality

Comment: you described the diagnostic clearly ... you determine the validity of an idea by running an experiment

Comment: My knowledge there goes as far as plugging the two cables together. What do I do after that?

Comment: I have used the program at `https://www.electronicwings.com/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-uart-communication-using-python-and-c` to test a serial wrap (jumper tx to rx) connection.